Issue with storing a text value in React on client side to then retrieving it on server side
I have an app that runs on http://localhost:3000/
In first page.tsx a user selects a category and is redirected to second page.tsx.
I want to store the selected category name here or in second page.tsx to then use it on the server side in route.ts, but unfortunately I cannot get it to work.
First page.tsx
"use client";

import React from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.css";

const Home = () => {
  const categories = {
    "Category 1": "category1",
    "Category 2": "category2",
  };

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.title}>
        Select category
      </div>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {Object.entries(categories).map(([name, url]) => (
          <a key={name} className={styles.category} href={`/examples/${url}`}>
            {name}
          </a>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


Second page.tsx
"use client";

import React from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.css"; // use simple styles for demonstration purposes
import Chat from "../../components/chat";

const Home = () => {

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Chat />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;


Route.ts
import { openai } from "@/app/openai";

export const runtime = "nodejs";

// Send a new message to a thread
export async function POST(request, { params: { threadId } }) {
  const { content } = await request.json();

  await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(threadId, {
    role: "user",
    content: content,
  });
  

  const stream = openai.beta.threads.runs.stream(threadId, {
    assistant_id: assistantId,
  });

  return new Response(stream.toReadableStream());
}

As React is used on the user side, I have tried useEffect and useState, Fetch(), store the value locally, cookies, but nothing works.
